# How to force a low recaptchaV3 score

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I need to be able to recreate low recaptchaV3 scores for testing purposes. I created a python script that calls my webpage with selenium using headless Firefox, fills and submits a form and scrapes the data and I'm still getting 0.9 scores.

I'm running this from my localhost so I assume that somehow recaptchaV3 has whitelisted my IP or something? In production I can verify that we are getting some bot activity and low scores and recaptchaV3 seems to be working as expected.

Not sure what else I could do, any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

### Edit

I spammed my own site with my python script and after thousands of requests I actually got some low scores, however when I tried again next day it went back to a static score of 0.9 and haven't been able to get a low score since.

Comment: Maybe the headless firefox has some old cookies that make it look human. Try it with a clean [profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles).

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but to no avail, still getting 0.9